# Line integral of this field: am I doing something wrong?

Tags: integration

I was asked to calculate the integral

$ \int_a^\infty F dr$

where $ F=\frac{k}{r}\vec{e_r}^{}$

k is a constant.

At first I thought this was pretty simple:

$ \int_a^\infty F dr= \int_a^\infty  \frac{k}{r} dr=[k\ln(r)]\Big|_a^\infty$

And well this integral is undefined (infinity).

However my professor came up with the answer:

$\frac{k}{a^2}$

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something because this is a line integral?

Comment: You are correct that the integral doesn't converge, maybe you have it written down wrong? Or that you were given that the field is defined to be zero at infinity. That still wouldn't make much sense though

Comment: Yes I confirmed with my professor and both the question and the answer were wrong lol

Comment: Well then I hope you now have the appropriate question and solution

Comment: Yes he meant us to calculate the integral of k/r^2... It makes sense since this is a revision of integral calculus to study electromagnetism and since the electric field of a charge q has a dependence of r^2.

Comment: Indeed then you accomplish finding the potential of a point charge